# How to unlink epic games to then link to my actual account?

Tags: xbox-one, fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher

OK so my son played fortnite on xbox and did not link his Epic Games account and now he is not connected to a new EG account and his Nintendo switch progress is not coming through, he is effectively back at 0 with no skins.

The option to relink does not appear on xboxand we do not know his Epic games account.

How can we unlink his xbox account from Epic Games so we can link his xbox account to his real Epic Games account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Reason is a GHOST Epic Games account has been created, and you no longer get the activation screen.

To sign into that GHOST account you need to set it up first.

Login to Epic Games using your Xbox Account, EPic games will ask you for Name and Details to setup account.

Once logged in you can now navigate to the "Account - Connected Accounts" area and Select the "Disconnect" for Xbox.

**Once this is done ensure you log out.**

**Be careful** of the email addresses used here, using the same email address caused me problems and required an email address change.
If your xbox and and proper Epic Game account already use the same email address, and you are setting up the Ghost account prior to disconnecting, then you could find that your Proper Account gets screwed up.

Once you have disconnected the Ghost Account you are free to start Fortnite again and this time correctly linking/activating EG, using your proper signed in Epic Games Account.

This process probably goes for all platforms, I know it does for Nintendo, and pretty sure for  Playstation.