# Move Epic account to a different Xbox gamer account

Tags: xbox-network, epic-games-launcher

Similar to [How to unlink epic games to then link to my actual account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363242/how-to-unlink-epic-games-to-then-link-to-my-actual-account), but not the same.

I have an Xbox live account, which is linked to my Epic account. My son doesn't like that when he plays Fortnite on the Xbox, his player name is my gamer tag. I want to create him his own Xbox account (free one), and then move the Epic account over to his gamer tag.

Is this possible? On the face of it, it seems so, but I will be the most hated man alive if he loses his Fortnite progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot disconnect an Epic Games account from an account on a console and reconnect it on an account of the same console type.

> Once you disconnect, you won't be able to connect a different console
> account of the same type to the same Epic Games account. Example: If
> you disconnect your Xbox account, you won't be able to add a different
> Xbox account to the same Epic Games account.

Source: https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/epic-accounts-c74/general-support-c79/how-do-i-disconnect-my-console-account-from-my-epic-games-account-a3253

Comment: Thank you. He'll have to keep my gamer tag then, or move back to the Switch.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now to do it once a year

If you don’t want to or can’t relink your original platform account, you can remove a restriction and link a new platform account once every 365 days (1 year). To make any changes, you must be logged in and have access to the email registered to your Epic Games account.

Comment: It would improve your post if you could link to a reputable source.